# Class parameter asynchronous affectation

Tags: javascript, class, async-await, parameters, static

hope you're doing good.

I wanted to know if it was possible to affect an async value to a class parameter in javascript, something like this :

```
export class MyClass {
static myParam = await myAsyncFunction();
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, and I would like to know how could I set it differently

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you use top-level `await`?

Comment: Just assign the promise (literally "*an async value*") to the property. But what exactly is your use case? What does `myAsyncFunction` do? Why do you need its result in a static class field, and where is that class field used?

Comment: I need to launch an external initialization function once in the instance of my class, and that function is asynchronous because it calls parameters from a parameter store asynchronously
I didn't found a way to just call it in the classe so i affected the result to a static property just for it to be called once
I have something like : 
`export class Index {
  static #ISINIT = await LambdaManager.init(routes);

//and some other methods
}`

Comment: If you want to do stuff on instances of the class, don't use `static` field. To run initialisation functions for instances, use an asynchronous factory function. I assume originally you tried to call this from the constructor?